# How to make Date Editable while using Glass mapper

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

Today i am facing one issue which has following requirement.

1. Date should be Editable.
2. Date should be in particular format.

My Code is like below which is not working.

```cs
foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <div>@Editable(item,  x => x.Start_Date.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy"))</div>
}
```

I have tried following approach but throwing "DateParameters" namespace error.

```cs
@Editable(item, x=> x.Start_Date, new DateParameters { Format = "MMMM dd,yyyy"})
```

Also i have learner following thing but how can i achieve this ?

To make a field editable takes two parameters, this has been used to make the Date field editable. The first parameter instructs Glass.Mapper which field to make editable, the second parameter then specifies what the output should be when the page is not in page editing mode. This allows you to control the output of the field when in the two different modes.

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

For Experience editor mode, this works for me in razor view:

`@Editable(model => model.SomeDateField, new { Format = "dd-MM-yyyy" })`

Sitecore 8.2 though, with Glass 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to provide the default format but keep things the same for the main glass stuff. Like so:

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <div>@Editable(item,  x => x.Start_Date, x=>x.Start_Date.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy"))</div>
}
```

This will make the date a normal date when editing, but allow you to format it for the final page.

Comment: I have tried that as well but it is throwing an error like below

 

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectToSwitchTo

 

   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)

   at Sitecore.Common.Switcher`2.Enter(TValue objectToSwitchTo)

   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression`1 field, Expression`1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context context, Database database, TextWriter writer)

 

Any help on this ?

Comment: If that's not working I would check that your model is wired up correctly, etc. I just confirmed the exact syntax here: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial5. If you don't have your model decorated correctly or something else like that, Glass wont' know how to map the field to the item in the tree correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in this case i use different code for "**Normal View**" and "**Experience Editor**", so for normal view you need only to display the date with format without making it editable, and on experience editor you need only to edit the date field the author will not care about the date format with experience editor, so  your code  will be like this :

```cs
foreach(var item in Model)
{
  {
    @if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing)
    {
      <div>@Editable(item,  x => x.Start_Date)</div>
    }
    else
    {
      <div>@item.Start_Date.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy")</div>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, we can do that but i want to achieve in single line code. As i feel glass mapper should provide such functionality.

Comment: This will work, if you have Title field i mean string field, glass mapper expecting from you date field but in your code, you are providing it with formatted date which is string.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried that as well but it is throwing an error like below

```
**Value cannot be null. Parameter name: objectToSwitchTo

   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Common.Switcher2.Enter(TValue objectToSwitchTo)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.GlassHtml.MakeEditable[T](Expression1 field, Expression1 standardOutput, T model, Object parameters, Context context, Database database, TextWriter writer)**
```

Any help on this ?